# Is there any way to apply a custom flow layout for a particular section in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I just want to use custom flowlayout for a particular section in UICollectionView. 
Different different layout for different sections.
Here is the attached image for reference.

[image]

Please help!!

Comment: You can use a cell dequeueReusableCell for the collectionview and style it on a if condition

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options. You could create two different types of cells or just create a second collection view. You also might be able to apply different layout attributes in your layout subclass depending on the index path's section. I'm not sure if that last idea is possible or even makes sense though as I haven't worked with iOS in a while and I don't remember ever trying this.